# How to stop Highmaps on mouse hover to change SVG path orders

Tags: highcharts

In all Highmaps when we hover on any particular country, the hoverd country SVG path put at the bottom in order to show hovered country on the top of others (the way we achieve z-index in svg).
I don't want Highmaps on mouse hover to change SVG path orders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap `zIndexSetter` method to call it only if the element is not a path:

```
(function(H) {
    H.wrap(H.SVGElement.prototype, 'zIndexSetter', function(proceed, value, key, el) {
        if (!el || (el && el.tagName !== 'path')) {
            return proceed.apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));
        }
    });
}(Highcharts));
```

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/31a0x4sL/

**Docs:** https://www.highcharts.com/docs/extending-highcharts

Comment: Perfect & Thanks @ppotaczek